# GraphQL schema to python dataclasses codegen

Tags: python, graphql, code-generation, type-hinting

I have a GraphQL schema defined from server and I'd like to write a nice Python GraphQL client for it. I'm looking for a way to transform my GraphQL schema into python classes with type hints such that I'll be able to see all available queries, mutations, their fields(names & types) and return vals.

I cannot write manually all python classes due to schema complexity, I have many filters on each field. see [this example](https://entgo.io/docs/tutorial-todo-gql-filter-input#configure-gql) from ent on `TodoWhereInput` to understand how error prune this will be. I really enjoy using `GraphQL playground` with auto completion, I want that experience in my python client.

For example, given this schema as an input:

```
type Book {
  title: String
  year: Int
}

type Author {
  name: String
  books: [Book]
}
```

I'd like to generate this python code as an output:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Book:
  title: str
  year: int

@dataclass
class Author:
  name: str
  books: list[Book]
```

same for `Input`s in schema.

I already looked at:

1. [codegen](https://www.the-guild.dev/graphql/codegen) which is awesome for typescript! but doesn't have python support :/
2. [gql_schema_codegen](https://github.com/sauldom102/gql_schema_codegen) nice, but generating `TypedDict` which isn't dataclasses, I have to change each dict and pass `total=False` so it won't required all fields by default.
3. [sgqlc code-generator](https://github.com/profusion/sgqlc#code-generator) which doesn't allow type hints. writing queries is still dynamically and error prune.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the answers, but after revisiting this issue I found out `Ariadne` is the best solution for my case. Generating async / sync clients based on GraphQL schema + queries, highly configurable.

You are welcome to try them yourself:
https://github.com/mirumee/ariadne-codegen

Answer (score 1):

I am actually working on a code generator, as part of a library that has the objective of allowing a code-first approach when querying GraphQL API servers from python.

To give you a preview what will be the outcome:

```
class Book(GQLObject):
  title: str
  year: int

class Author(GQLObject):
  name: str
  books: list[Book]
```

I just published the core of the mapper on github:

https://github.com/dapalex/py-graphql-mapper/

Have a look at the documentation and I hope to publish the code generator soon.

Answer (score 1):

you can to use my project for data-model generation from some GraphQL schema file https://denisart.github.io/graphql2python/

Now it works!
New settings will be added soon for more flexible generation:

- custom imports;
- custom templates;
- render of InputObject;
- hooks for render;

Simple example for https://countries.trevorblades.com/ schema and gql client:
https://denisart.github.io/graphql2python/gql.html

Also, we can to use the package for GraphQL queries generation with python classes https://denisart.github.io/graphql-query/

Comment: This works perfectly if you already have a graphql.schema file. The documentation says to run the render command, but it doesn't exists. Instead use the generate command and pass in the config file.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another example on how to generate classes from a GQL schema can be found in [qenerate](https://github.com/app-sre/qenerate). It creates simple data classes for queries and even supports the use of fragments to reduce repetitive class generation. The schema is obtained by leveraging GraphQL's [Introspection](https://graphql.org/learn/introspection/) feature.

qenerate itself is not a client. It is intended to be used along-side other GQL clients. It solely focuses on generating corresponding classes for given query/fragment definitions.

Disclaimer: I work on the team that created qenerate.

Answer (score 0):

There is also [sgqlc](https://github.com/profusion/sgqlc?tab=readme-ov-file#code-generator) that can generate the schema and code and execute the queries.